# Inserting tags v categories via PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, categories

Im trying to insert the category

```
$apples = "granny smith"
```

as part of a new post.

I can create a new post with a TAG easily with the following script:

```
$my_post = array(
    'post_title' => $title,
    'post_content' => $content,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_author' => 1,
    'tags_input' => $apples,
    'post_type' => 'post'
    );
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

But for some reason, despite that the WP codex lists

```
'post_category'
```

for categories, the following code does NOT create the new category "granny smith" and instead, enters the new post as "uncategorized" :

```
$my_post = array(
    'post_title' => $title,
    'post_content' => $content,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_category' => $apples
    'post_type' => 'post'
    );
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

Can someone help me w the code please? Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accordning to [the documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) it looks like the categories should be added as an array with the category id's:

```
$id_for_category_ganny_smith = 12;
$my_post = array(
    'post_title' => $title,
    'post_content' => $content,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_category' => array($id_for_category_ganny_smith),
    'post_type' => 'post'
    );
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

The documentation states:

> Categories need to be passed as an array of integers that match the
>   category IDs in the database. This is the case even where only one
>   category is assigned to the post.

If you don't know the id of the categories you want to add, you can try the following:

```
$apples_slug = "granny_smith"
$my_post = array(
    'post_title' => $title,
    'post_content' => $content,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'post'
    );
$post_ID = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
wp_set_post_terms( $post_ID, $apples_slug, 'category')
```

Comment: Thanks and its appreciated!